# How to append vectors inside lists with grace

Tags: r

I have a vector appended within a list. The entry successively grows.

```
li <- list()
for(i in 1:10)
{
  v <- runif(2)
  if(i==1)
  {
    li[[1]] <- v
  } else {
    li[[1]] <- append(li[[1]],v)
  }
}
```

It's ugly that I need different code for the two cases 1) `li[[1]]` does not exist and 2) `li[[1]]` exists. Any solutions?

Background:
you cant initialize a list element as you do it with a vector:

```
v <- NULL
v <- append(v,c(1,2,3))
```

works

but

```
li <- list()
li[[1]] <- NULL
li[[1]] <- append(li[[1]],c(1,2,3))
```

throws an error, since `li[[1]]` can't be initialized by `li[[1]] <- NULL` .

Update: I learned that this will work with named lists (which also adds some grace), but there may be (dynamical) cases where naming is not a good option.

Comment: Why are you using a loop and a list? Simply use `matrix(runif(2*10), ncol=10)`.

Comment: @Roland It's not about simplifying the play example, ist about concatenating vectors to a list element that may not exist

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to do something like this, you should always reconsider. It's a safe bet that there is a better alternative in R, usually with problems similar to your example it's `lapply` (assuming that an R loop is needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that you need a `loop` here. But you can pre-allocate your list to avoid dealing with empty lists. You allocate using `vector` like this:

```
n <- 10
li <- vector('list',n)
```

Then you just assign each element :

```
for(i in 1:10) {
  v <- runif(sample(n,1)) ## I choose a dynamic length here 
                          ## otherwise the example don't make sense
  li[[i]] <- v
}
```

Comment: sure, in this play example no loop is needed. But thanks for the helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to initialize list elements is such:

```
li <- list(NULL)
for(i in 1:10)
{
  v <- runif(2)
  li[[1]] <- append(li[[1]],v)
}
```

Thanks